# How to change primary monitor on hardware layer?

Tags: uefi, multiple-monitors

With my family we sometimes use TV as second monitor, when I don't need to enter grub it's ok, but if I want to swap OS or change something in UEFI it starts with TV as primary, so I don't see anything, can I somehow change this? In bios I looked at every option, so my only gues is to do it somehow using linux.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Perhaps you can change the port?  When you see GRUB, no operating system has been loaded yet, so nothing you do in Ubuntu will affect this.

Comment: there is one problem with ports, I have only one hdmi, and one that weird I have in monitor... sooo... this would solved problem if possible.

In linux I meant rewriting something in bios memory if it's possible... (in windows surely not)

Comment: Your BIOS is your motherboard firmware and is unrelated to any operating system. Trying to alter firmware is not a good idea and can result in you bricking your motherboard.

Comment: I know what's BIOS... it's saved on little ROM memory on motherboard and loads before anything, makes everything working etc... but it can be edited from inside... some parts of it are blocked... I wanted to know if it's possible to edit it using terminal...

Comment: If you think you can edit it, you know more than I do.   I would not recommend making any changes to your BIOS that you can't do using its own settings.  This process would be hardware specific if you can do it at all.  Even if you could make changes from within the operating system that's a really risky idea.  Some manufacturers in the past have attempted to include software that updates the BIOS to newer versions (instead of flashing from the BIOS settings) and those softwares are plagued with people bricking their hardware from the slightest hiccup.  I suggest that you not pursue this path.

Comment: ok... so I'll do with unpluging hdmi besfore startup :D (surely it's plug'n play)